# How to use ToDictionary to convert a query result into a dictionary

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, dictionary

I have this query in EF:

```
var data = db.Inventario.Where(i => i.ClienteId.Equals(Global.ClienteID))
   .GroupBy(i => new { Tipo = i.Tipo.TipoNombre, Zona = i.Localidad.Zona.ZonaNombre, Localidad = i.Localidad.LocalidadNombre })
   .Select(i => new Registro()
      {
         Tipo = i.Key.Tipo,
         Zona = i.Key.Zona,
         Localidad = i.Key.Localidad,
         Estados = i.SelectMany(ei => ei.EstadoInventario)
            .GroupBy(ei => ei.Estado.EstadoNombre)
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ToDictionary(ei => ei.Key, ei => ei.Sum(item => item.EstadoInventarioValor ? 1 : 0))
      });

this.Data = data.ToList();
```

When I run it, this error occurs:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionay`2[System.String,System.Int32]
>   ToDictionary[IGrouping`2,String,Int32](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Linq.IGrouping`2[System.String,Data.EstadoInventario]],
>   System.Func`2[System.Linq.IGrouping`2

Estados property of Registro class is a Dictionary where I need to store a dictionary of key EstadoNombre with the value of the sum of records in the query result.

Comment: Put an `AsEnumerable()` before `ToDictionary` to pull the result from the server first.

Comment: It did not work. I have updated the question. Error occurs in data.ToList() instruction

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you had the `ToDictionary` inside the `Select` - move the `ToEnumerable` before the `Select`. This may have performance consequences. Note that calling `GroupBy` followed by `ToDictionary` may not be the most efficient thing to do. Depending on server performance I would put the `AsEnumerable` before the first `GroupBy` to minimize server queries to one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LINQ to Entities translates your LINQ expressions to SQL statements (or anything else based on your provider) to get you the data you need. However, not all expressions can be translated easily to SQL (i.e. `ToDictionary` function call), this is why the runtime complains.

So you have to *materialize* your query (i.e. fetch the data from the database and turn it into objects) before using any of these *unrecognized* expressions.

To do that you can simply call `ToList()` on your `IQueryable` to get a list of objects from your *query*, then you will be able to call `ToDictionary` on that list of objects.

I didn't test the below code but it depicts the idea.

```
var query = db.Inventario.Where(i => i.ClienteId.Equals(Global.ClienteID))
                .GroupBy(i => new { Tipo = i.Tipo.TipoNombre, Zona = i.Localidad.Zona.ZonaNombre, Localidad = i.Localidad.LocalidadNombre })
                .Select(i => new { Tipo = i.Key.Tipo, Zona = i.Key.Zona, Localidad = i.Key.Localidad, Estados = i.SelectMany(ei => ei.EstadoInventario).GroupBy(ei => ei.Estado.EstadoNombre) });

var data = query.ToList().Select(i => new Registro { Tipo = i.Tipo, Zona = i.Zona, Localidad = i.Localidad, Estados = i.Estodas.ToDictionary(ei => ei.Key, ei => ei.Sum(item => item.EstadoInventarioValor ? 1 : 0)) });
```

Comment: The only problem is performance..... I think I should implement another technique

Comment: @jstuardo something like dividing data into chunks might help